# Notepad++ Reg Expression Find and replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have the following:

```
$Variable = $Row['Title'];
$Variable = $Row['FirstName'];
$Variable = $Row['MiddleName'];
$Variable = $Row['LastName'];
$Variable = $Row['KnownAs'];
$Variable = $Row['FullName'];
```

but want to replace the $Variable with the name between '', so the above should look like this:

```
$Title = $Row['Title'];
$FirstName = $Row['FirstName'];
$MiddleName = $Row['MiddleName'];
$LastName = $Row['LastName'];
$KnownAs = $Row['KnownAs'];
$FullName = $Row['FullName'];
```

How do i do this in Notepad++

Comment: telling us what you have already tried might get you some responses...because now it looks like you haven't put any effort into it at all

Comment: Sorry, i have tried to find between ' ' using: $Row['(.*)\']; and tried Replace: $\1 = $Row['\1, but that found not results. I also tried Find: '(.*?)' which actually got between the ' ', but then struggled to replace the $Variable part as used Replace: $0$1

Answer (score 3):

Find:

```
\$Variable( = \$Row\['(\w+)'\];)
```

Replace:

```
$\2\1
```

Explanation:

- `\$` because the dollar sign is a special character that needs to be escaped.
- `( = \$Row\['(\w+)'\];)` is the 1st capturing group, that you want essentially to replicate.
- `(\w+)` is the 2nd capturing group, where `\w` is a word character, and `+` means "at least 1".

Screenshot:
[image]